# Dynamic and multiple ngTemplate in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have angular 7 app. And I have a `gridComponent` and I'm using it from `app.component.html` . I want to create some columns dynamically from my `app.component.ts`. And, so I create my codes like below. But, in my grid, `student` and `manager` columns coming empty. What can be the reason of this problem? **I added the final version that I want of the painting to the bottom of the page.**

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwzmpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be simple with the help of custom directive like:

**cell-template.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ng-template[cellTemplate]'
})
export class CellTemplateDirective {
  @Input('cellTemplate') name: string;

  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

Having this directive you can define templates for your types:

```
<app-grid>
  <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" cellTemplate="student">student {{rowData}}</ng-template>
  <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" cellTemplate="manager">manager {{rowData}}</ng-template>
</app-grid>
```

Also your grid component should know how to handle specific template:

**grid.component.ts**

```
@ContentChildren(CellTemplateDirective) cellTemplates: QueryList<CellTemplateDirective>;

cellTemplatesMap: { [key: string]: TemplateRef<any> };

...

ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.cellTemplatesMap = this.cellTemplates.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.name] = cur.template;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

I query created early directive by using `@ContentChildren` decorator and also transform these array to simple key-value map to avoid redundant computation.

The last piece of the solution is to provide correct template in html:

**grid.component.html**

```
<td *ngIf="column.type==='template'">
    <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="cellTemplatesMap[column.columnName]; ...
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-35xgvk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks a lot @yurzui. This is what I was looking for. But, I don't understand why we are using `ngAfterContentInit` and what are we doing in `ngAfterContentInit`.

Comment: I used `ngAfterContentInit` hook because that's the right place where we can get all projected content initialized

Comment: There I use `reduce` method to transform array of `CellTemplateDirective` to key value dictionary.like `{ student: TemplateRef, manager: TemplateRef }`

Comment: It helps us to get fast access to the dedicated template. Otherwise we would use something like `getTemplateByName(name) { return this.cellTemplates.find(x => x.name === name); }` and it would be executed every change detection cycle

Comment: Thank again your help @yurzui

Comment: Yurzui, I applid this grid in my real scenario now. But, in my real scenario, length of `cellTemplates` in `ngAfterContentInit` method, is coming zero. So, my columns coming empty. Is, there any way, doing this without using `ngAfterContentInit` @yurzui.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: My real grid component is very complex @yurzui. And I'm using `PrimeNg`. So, code won't build. I think, I applied the same thing in above stackblitz to my real app. But maybe, I overlooked something. I added my not builded codes this stackblitz link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xoyans?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid.component.ts

Comment: I think, if is possible without using ngAfterContentInit , then problem will solve @yurzui . Is it possible?

Comment: It length of ContentChildren becomes 0 then you didn't define CellTemplateDirective on your projected content

Comment: Thanks @yurzui. I can finally reproduce my problem. You can see from stackblitz link easily https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-37onux . The problem occurs when you create new component and call grid from it. For example, in this example I create `home.component` . But, when I write `<app-grid>` in my `home.component` . Then `student` and `manager` colums coming empty. Can you check please this stackblitz?

Comment: That's because you didn't add `CellTemplateDirective` to `declarations` array. It should be in the same place where you declare `GridComponent`. Check `AppRoutingModule` module. Maybe you should consider creating SharedModule where you put grid and directive in declarations and exports arrays. Then import `SharedModule` in any module you want to use grid. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-grsvky?file=app/app.routing.module.ts

Comment: Yes. In my real app, `gridcomponent` is in my `shared.module` . I applied to my app, and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot @yurzui .